# Devexpress file manager using asp.net file system provider

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, devexpress

I implemented devextreme to my react project.I'm using file manager system and I'm using devexpress for create system provider with my asp.net project.

I have an issue.

When i try to upload any file I'm getting and error.Download,move,copy is working very well.But i cant upload any file.

File uploaded succesfully my temp folder but then doesnt move to my real path.How can i fix this.Devexpress version 20.1

```
public object FileSystem(long id, FileSystemCommand command, string arguments, HttpRequest Request)
    {
        
        var path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "../files/Images/", id.ToString());

        var config = new FileSystemConfiguration
        {
            Request = Request,
            FileSystemProvider = new PhysicalFileSystemProvider(
                path,
                (fileSystemItem, clientItem) =>
                {
                    if (!clientItem.IsDirectory)
                        clientItem.CustomFields["url"] = GetFileItemUrl(fileSystemItem, Request);
                }
            ),
            //uncomment the code below to enable file/folder management
            AllowCopy = true,
            AllowCreate = true,
            AllowMove = true,
            AllowDelete = true,
            AllowRename = true,
            AllowUpload = true,
            AllowDownload = true,
            AllowedFileExtensions = new[] { ".txt", ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".csv" }
        };
        var processor = new FileSystemCommandProcessor(config);

        var result = processor.Execute(command, arguments);
        return result.GetClientCommandResult();
    }
```

Here is the front end code

```
import React from "react";
import FileManager, { Permissions } from "devextreme-react/file-manager";
import RemoteFileSystemProvider from "devextreme/file_management/remote_provider";
import { Popup } from "devextreme-react/popup";

let remoteProvider = new RemoteFileSystemProvider({
    endpointUrl: "https://myapiurl.com.tr/api/FileManager/FileSystem/121",
});
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentPath: "Widescreen",
            popupVisible: false,
            imageItemToDisplay: {},
            remoteProvider: new RemoteFileSystemProvider({
                endpointUrl: "https://myapiurl.com.tr/api/FileManager/FileSystem/121",
            }),
        };

        this.displayImagePopup = this.displayImagePopup.bind(this);
        this.hideImagePopup = this.hideImagePopup.bind(this);
        this.onCurrentDirectoryChanged = this.onCurrentDirectoryChanged.bind(this);
    }

    displayImagePopup(e) {
        this.setState({
            popupVisible: true,
            imageItemToDisplay: {
                name: e.file.name,
                url: e.file.dataItem.url,
            },
        });
    }

    hideImagePopup() {
        this.setState({
            popupVisible: false,
        });
    }
    onCurrentDirectoryChanged(e) {
        this.setState({
            currentPath: e.component.option("currentPath"),
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(remoteProvider);
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.investment ? (
                    <div>
                        <FileManager
                            currentPath={this.state.currentPath}
                            fileSystemProvider={remoteProvider}
                            onSelectedFileOpened={this.displayImagePopup}
                            onCurrentDirectoryChanged={this.onCurrentDirectoryChanged}
                        >
                            <Permissions
                                create={true}
                                copy={true}
                                move={true}
                                delete={true}
                                rename={true}
                                upload={true}
                                download={true}
                            ></Permissions>
                        </FileManager>

                        <Popup
                            maxHeight={600}
                            closeOnOutsideClick={true}
                            title={this.state.imageItemToDisplay.name}
                            visible={this.state.popupVisible}
                            onHiding={this.hideImagePopup}
                            className="photo-popup-content"
                        >
                            <img src={this.state.imageItemToDisplay.url} className="photo-popup-image" />
                        </Popup>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    ""
                )}
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue lately, if I'm not mistaken, it was related to a mismatch between some DLLs versions of the project. The client-side version must match the FileSystemCommandeProcessor version. The DevExtreme team seems to have changed some property name which cause this issue.